# matlab evaluate current line (where cursor is)

Tags: matlab, undocumented-behavior

How do I do the same as F9, but without marking the current line (e.g. with shift+home, then F9)?

Obviously this is purely for convenience sake - but something like shift-F9 or ctrl+F9 would be cool?

How to make that shortcut? Would any poweruser know?

Comment: Check out [Matlab-Editor-Plugin](https://github.com/GavriYashar/Matlab-Editor-Plugin/wiki/Features#execute-current-lines) which allows executing the current line using shift-F9, without the need for selecting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not trivial to create you own action for a keyboard shortcut in Matlab (you can see predefined shortcuts in Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts). [Check this discussion for help though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274998/enabling-option-key-shortcuts-in-matlab-for-mac)

Alternatively, if it works for you, you can easily select a line and then press F9. To quickly select a line, choose one of these steps:

> 1. triple click anywhere on the line
> 2. click on the space between the break-point gutter and the start of the line

[Mathworks link to selecting a whole line](https://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/05/03/selecting-a-whole-line/)